# Is it possible to have a square resolution with a webcam video stream using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

I wrote a simple OpenCV program that recovers my webcam video stream and display it on a simple window. I wante to resize this window to the resolution 256x256 but it changed it to 320x240.

Here's my source code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char key;
    cvNamedWindow("Camera_Output", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
    CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);

    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 256);
    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 256);

    while(1){

        IplImage *frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

        cvShowImage("Camera_Output", frame);

        key = cvWaitKey(10);
        if (key == 27){
            break;
        }
    }
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    cvDestroyWindow("Camera_Output");

    return 0;
}
```

The output resolution is 320x240 and I want a 256x256 resolution. I think it's not possible because the camera manages its output video stream buffer and it has to keep the same ratio (width/height). What do you think about this idea ?

Is there a function which can force the resolution as a square resolution using OpenCV ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: `cv::namedWindow()` uses a default parameter `int flags=WINDOW_AUTOSIZE`. change it to `cv::namedWindow("windowname",WINDOW_NORMAL)` and you will be able to resize the window. The other possibility would be to resize the image and display it full sized in the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you video source does not handle 256x256 resolution. If you want to display it as such, you will have to crop the image yourself before displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you can do this by:

```
VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(0); // open your web-camera
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 256); 
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 256);
```

If this doesn't work, you need to resize it manually by calling `cv::resize()`.

Comment: This is exactly the same as the code in the question, just in C++ instead of C. But I just noticed you made the answer before the source code was added to the question.